# Can a pandas series be a column rather than a row?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a real question, though it may seem to be splitting hairs at first glance.  Basically I want to treat a series as a column rather than a row, which I think makes intuitive sense even if series can not technically be divided into rows and columns (?) whereas 1d numpy arrays can.  The example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'a' : [5,3,1],
                     'b' : [4,6,2],
                     'c' : [2,4,9] } )

df['rowsum'] = df.sum(1)

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
   a  b  c  rowsum
0  5  4  2      11
1  3  6  4      13
2  1  2  9      12
```

I just want to get percentages by row (so rows sum to 1).  I would like to do this:

```
df.iloc[:,0:3] / df.rowsum
```

which works fine in numpy (with reshape) since you can make rowsum a column or row vector.  But here I can't reshape the series or use T on df.rowsum.  It seems a dataframe can be transposed but not a series.  The following works (along with several other solutions).  And it can be coded naturally in numpy, but that involves converting to arrays and then back to a dataframe.

```
In [32]: ( df.iloc[:,0:3].T / df.rowsum ).T
Out[32]: 
          a         b         c
0  0.454545  0.363636  0.181818
1  0.230769  0.461538  0.307692
2  0.083333  0.166667  0.750000
```

I'm sorry if this seems trivial but it's valuable to be able to code in terms of rows and columns in an intuitive way.  So the question is merely: can I make a series act like a column vector rather than a row vector?

Also it seems inconsistent that this will work fine on a column.

`df.iloc[:,0] / df.rowsum`

pandas appears in this case to be dividing (elementwise) two column arrays (on account of the display, even if the row/column distinction is artificial).  But when the first part of that expression is changed from a dataframe to series, it seems to effectively go from being a 3x1 to a 1x2.  It's like going from a series to a dataframe is an implicit transform operation?

Maybe a better way to think about it:

```
all( dist.iloc[:,:10].index == dist.rowsum.index )
Out[1526]: True
```

The indexes line up here, why does pandas seem to employ the index differently for series/series broadcasting than for dataframe/series broadcasting?  Or am I just thinking about this completely wrong?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
df.apply(lambda x:x/x[3], axis = 1)

        a          b           c    rowsum
0   0.454545    0.363636    0.181818    1
1   0.230769    0.461538    0.307692    1
2   0.083333    0.166667    0.750000    1
```

If you don't need the rowsum column, you can use

```
df.apply(lambda x:x/sum(x), axis = 1) #with your original dataFrame
```

Comment: Thanks!  Probably the most readable way to do it, although I generally try to avoid apply/lambda if possible for speed reasons if there is a good alternative (though speed is not a concern here).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df.iloc[:, 0:3].div(df.rowsum, axis=0)
```

to see if it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a good practical approach although I'm still searching for a deeper understanding.

Comment: Check the [DataFrame.div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html#pandas.DataFrame.div) help and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior) for more detail.